# Multiple result set in PHP?

Tags: php, resultset

In .NET SqlDataReader can retrieve multiple record set:

```
    Dim Connection As New SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString)
    'Note that the command will generate three result
    Dim Command As New SqlCommand("select '1a', '1b'; " & _
        "select '2a', '2b', '2c'; " & _
        "select '3a', '3b'; ", Connection)
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader

    Connection.Open()

    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

    Do
        While Reader.Read
            'Do something with the data
        End While
    Loop While (Reader.NextResult) 'Proceed to next result

    Reader.Close()
    Connection.Close()
```

The `.NextResult` moves the reader to the next result. How to do this in PHP? I basically want to avoid many round trips to the database.

Note: `.Read` here moves the next row while `.NextResult` moves to the next result.

1 query, 3 results:

result 1

```
1a 1b
```

result 2

```
2a 2b 2c
```

result 3

```
3a 3b
```

Note: Row is not equal to result. Result is much more like a table or set of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this if you are using PDO, by using [PDOStatement->nextRowset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php).  Whether this is supported or not depends entirely on the database you are connecting to, and which PDO driver you use.

Comment: I think this is it. MySQL or MSSQL? What do you think?

Comment: I don't think MySQL (or at least the PDO mysql driver) supports multiple result sets.  PostgreSQL might, and I don't have any firsthand experience with PDO's SQL Server driver, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: Noooooooo!! I'll just do some research on that. Thanks1

Comment: PDO MySQL does support multiple result sets by the way.